# Please help me with the "new" keyword

Tags: c#, new-operator

I'm new to c# but i really want to understand about the "new" keyword in c# to know how to use it in future, i've seens alot of basic video about c# using new keyword but i just copy them without any knowledges and it makes my quite uncomfortable, i've searched it on google alot but only understand a few things, the most hardest thing for me to understand is "it creates a new empty object", can someone explain it for me?

And why i can't just create an object like this if i don't have any constructors

```
Class1 student = Class1(); //i got an error with this but it's still not help me understand the new keyword
```

When will i need to create an array like this

```
string[] myArr = new string[0];
```

not like this

```
string[] myArr = {};
```

It'll be nice if someone can give me some easy-to-understand example :P
Everytime i searching about the new keyword, my brain just overthinking it :'D

Comment: " if I don't have any constructors" there is always a constructor. If you do not define any constructors, there will be a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: "And why i can't just create an object like this" Because that's not how the language is designed.

Comment: If tutorial doesn't work well, perhaps you need to try another form of learning? Online courses (where you can ask questions), books for beginners (where explanation of basic things is well thought and is detailed), etc.

Comment: Construction of **arrays** is unrelated to class constructors. Yes, they both use the `new` keyword, but they are completely different things. Array constructors are not functions. The brackets alone are a _shortcut_ for an array constructor, so you should really just ignore that at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between Classes and Objects.
Objects are an instantiation of a Class.

For example, if you have a `House` class, you can have multiple `House`-objects based on it.
Every time you want to create (in the analogy: build) a new house, you have to use the `new` keyword.

For example:

```
House myHouse = new House();
myHouse.openDoor(); //Opens the door of house 1

House neighboursHouse = new House(); //My neighbour likes to live in a house too, but I dont want him in my house. I create a new House.
neighboursHouse.ringDoorbell() // I don't have a key to my neighbours house.
```

Comment: You really good at spreading knowledges xD, i got the objects now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The new statement is used to create objects or to call previously created objects.
For Example:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.writesomething();

        string[] myArr = new string[2];
        myArr[0] = "string text";
        myArr[1] = "other string text";
        string[] newArr = myArr;
        Console.WriteLine(newArr[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(newArr[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Class1
{
  public void writesomething(string text = "cool text")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

If you put breakpoint you will see that newarr gets the value myarr

Comment: "The new statement is used [...] to call previously created objects". Maybe you mean that creating a new object *implicitely* calls the constructor of the class as part of the creation process? Otherwise this it is just wrong.

Answer (score -1):

new is very difficult to understand for a beginner. I have been learning C++ and C# for 3 years now and I am still not absolutely sure. But from my understanding, the main difference between using `int array[5];` and `int[] array = new int[5];` is that the former is stack-allocated memory and the latter is heap-allocated memory. stack memory is allocated during compilation and heap allocation is done while the program is running. The very first time I learned about this difference is when I found out you can do this:

```
int x = 5;
int[] array = new int[x]
```

when you are creating an array with the new keyword, the length of the array does not require to be a compile-time constant. The new keyword is used to instantiate an object of a class but the main difference between `ClassName newObject;` and `ClassName newObject = new ClassName;` is that the former is stack allocation, and the latter is heap allocation. You can use either in C++ but I believe you can only use heap allocation in C#.

Please feel free to correct me in the comments if I am wrong. I am not an expert and my understanding might also be flawed :)

Comment: `int array[5];` is not allowed in C#. You can use `stackalloc` instead, but that's an advantaged case.

Comment: Thank u, i think i just got it a little bit xD